# The Cartesian product of 2 embeddings is an embedding.

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I am trying to solve this question:

Show that the Cartesian product $f_1 \times f_2: N_1 \times N_2 \to M_1 \times M_2,$ of two embeddings $f_1, f_2$ is again an embedding.

My definition of an embedding is:

> [image]
> My definition of an $n$-dimensional smooth submanifold is:

> [image]
> [image]
> It is easy for me to prove that the composition of two diffeomorphisms is again a diffeomorphism. But how can I prove that the composition of two submanifolds is again a submanifold, it is for me true according to intuition.

The hint at the back of the book is:

> [image]

My question is:

I do not know why the hint is saying reduce to the case where $f$ and $g$ are inclusions of submanifolds, how will this help us in the proof? could someone help me in answering this question please?

Also, what does it mean to "rearrange some coordinates" that is mentioned in the hint? could someone help me answer this please?

**Some facts:**

Assume that $f_1: N_1 \to M_1$ is an embedding, then $f(N_1) \subset M_1$ is a differentiable submanifold and $f_1: N_1 \to f(N_1)$ is a diffeomorphism.

Also, Assume that $f_2: N_2 \to M_2$ is an embedding, then $f(N_2) \subset M_2$ is a differentiable submanifold and $f_2: N_2 \to f(N_2)$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Are you sure that in your setup you don't mean to have $f_1(N_1)\subseteq N_2$?.

Comment: Is that because we are composing?@JacobSmith I do not see your point, could you please clarify it?

Comment: Partially. Since you want to talk about composition, you will want the second map to have $f_1(N_1)$ in its domain - otherwise you aren't composing the two maps. Assuming that $f_1(N_1)$ and $N_2$ *do* live in the same space (it seems like you're thinking of the two as just being submanifolds of some larger manifold), then without specifying conditions on their intersection you don't even know that the intersection is a (sub)manifold. E.g. $f_1(N_1)$ is the unit sphere at the origin and $N_2$ is the union of a unit sphere centered at (2,0,0) and a unit sphere centered at $(-1,0,0)$.